# Efficiently write avro record to avro file

Tags: avro

how can I efficiently add new avro record to an existing avro file. My avro file will keep on increasing in size, and I dont want to open file into memory.Could you please tell us how efficiently we can achieve this.

Comment: Which language are you trying to do this in? Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFileWriter.appendTo`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/file/DataFileWriter.html#appendTo(java.io.File)). This won't load the existing file's contents in memory. (Under the hood, it will read the beginning of the file to find the schema and other metadata, then append to the end without loading what's in between.)

If you'd like to do this on HDFS, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/QwertyManiac/4724582) might be a good place to start as well.

Comment: How can I avoid loading a file(which has size upto Giga bytes) into memory while doing avro serialization.
Is there a way avro can support loading file and serialize only when it is writing to avro file.??

Comment: The above doesn't load the entire file in memory so will work fine even if your file is multiple GBs. (Not sure if the confusion comes from there but when you write `new File(somePath)` in Java, it doesn't load the file's contents into memory, it mostly just does some path parsing logic.)

Comment: But in my case, I have to send the file pointer which is stored in hdfs, construct some metadata for file and save the record(along with metadata and file by serializing through avro) to hdfs again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "along with metadata and file by serializing through avro" but the gist linked above shows how you would append records to a file on HDFS (if your cluster supports appending to files). If you updated your question with a concrete example of what you'd like to do (clarifying what metadata you are writing, etc.), that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your question and related technology is ambiguous; but I will make an attempt to answer as best as I understand.
I will assume that you are doing this in HDFS.

`data in dir vs files`:

in HDFS, you can think in terms of directories rather than files.
The tools in Hadoop ecosystem, for e.g. hive or spark allow you to read "data" from directories without regard to the number of files stored in the dir.
This way, you add files to the directory and your "queries" will progressively display or fetch increasing amount of data.

`AVRO , record based`:

I'd think of an AVRO file as an avro record. LEt's say that you have an avro schema and you generate an object in memory/in your program/code and you convert that to AVRO format. This object will translate to one avro record. If you write that data to a file, that will be one avro record. over the course of 10 days, if you write 10 files in the same dir, you will now have 10 records, when you read the "directory".

`immutability`:

generally, I'd think of HDFS data as immutable. any file written is mostly to be read rather than modified. Same would apply to AVRO record as well, which is nothing but a file with schema and data. i.e. you will generally, never read the same file and modify it. I am assuming that you will be adding new data rather than modifying it. Consequently, you will be just creating new records.

`serialize multiple objects to one file`:

Now let's consider you truly want to write "multiple" objects to one file. 
I will assume that you actually have these multiple objects in your hand/code at a given point in time and want to persist to a single file.
if you use `jackson-dataformat-avro`, it provides a `SequenceWriter` to do just that.

```
SequenceWriter w = mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(mySingleAvroFile); 
w.write(firstObject); 
w.write(secondObject); 
...
w.close();
```